# Symfony2 abstract class multiple inheritance with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, abstract

I got following UML scheme :
[image]

Basically, it's the beginning of taxonomy system with some of them nestable, and some not.
I started to try making 2 layers of abstract classes (Taxonomy and OfferCategory) because none of them can be used as a final entity. I used MappedSuperClass, but I got following error :

```
[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]                                                                                       
Column name `id` referenced for relation from LCH\CatalogBundle\Entity\HomeOfferCategory towards LCH\CatalogBund       le\Entity\OfferCategory does not exist.
```

My primary key field is id...

In a more general point of view, what's the best implementation for my scheme provided with Doctrine?

Thanks !

**EDIT :** I tried to transpose all OfferCategory members directly in my RootOfferCategory class. By changing th targetENtity on both sides, no more error.
**Meaning you can't self reference a mapped super class?**

**Taxonomy :**

```
/**
* Class Taxonomy
* @package LCH\CatalogBundle\Entity
* @ORM\MappedSuperclass
*/
abstract class Taxonomy implements TaxonomyInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string the category name
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
     protected $name;
}
```

**OfferCategory : **

```
/**
 * OfferCategory
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class OfferCategory extends Taxonomy
{
   /**
    * @var OfferCategory the category parent
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="LCH\CatalogBundle\Entity\OfferCategory",inversedBy="children", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referenceColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $parent;
   /**
   * @var OfferCategory the children categories
   *       @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LCH\CatalogBundle\Entity\OfferCategory",mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist"})
   */
   protected $children;
}
```

**RootOfferCategory**

```
/**
 * RootOfferCategory
 * Represents one root top category
 * @ORM\Table()
 *      @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="LCH\CatalogBundle\Entity\RootOfferCategoryRepository")
 */
class RootOfferCategory extends OfferCategory
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to arrive after the war.

From [this part](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) of the Doctrine documentation :

> A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able and persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must be unidirectional (with an owning side only).
>
> This means that One-To-Many associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all.
>   Furthermore Many-To-Many associations are only possible if the mapped superclass is only used in exactly one entity.At the moment.
>
> For further support of inheritance, the single or joined table inheritance features have to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I discover that while reading again the Doctrine2 doc... Nonetheless, is there another way to model my case in order to keep parent relation unique and not duplicated?

Comment: Extend an entity (no really need of the `@ORM\Entity` annotation) rather than a mapped super-class, the child entities will inherit the properties with their mapping. I use a simple class containing just a mapped identifier to avoid writing it in in all my entities, and it works perfectly, with or without the entity annotation, abstract or not ... Doctrine works well with classes inheritance.